# Winform and WPF Window border

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, border

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the style of WinForm border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613418/change-the-style-of-winform-border)
>   [Form border size and color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976546/form-border-size-and-color)

Ok, I´m rewritting this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976546/form-border-size-and-color, dont know why they closed it. I want to know how can i change the border size and color of my forms(WINFORM) and WPF windows. I´m using right now Fixed Tool Window as border type. I also hide the buttons (Minimize - Maximize - Close). But the border is still thick, and i dont want to have windows theme, but a black color border. Does anybody know how to implement this? I dont need resizing.

Some considerations:

- The solution needs to be useful in both Winform and WPF.
- The window or form needs to be moveable.
- I wanted to change the color and size of the Window OS border for my app. But I know it uses Windows API and that can be hard.

And don´t vote negative if you don´t understand, just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: who voted negative and why?

Comment: I think your question is not clear if you are asking about winforms or WPF. I answered assuming is WPF

Comment: Yeah LarsTech, because that question was mine and they close it.

Comment: All right then. Anyway I wasn't downvoted you

Answer (score 0):

`.FormBorderStyle = None` should do it.

Comment: I want a thin border, not no border.

Comment: Then you will have to make your own.

Comment: isnt there a way to paint the non-client area(border) with the color i want at least?

Comment: sure, handle the WM_NCPAINT message yourself

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this? You need to remove all the "Windows Style" and then customize it using, for example, a `Border` element as a container for the window. Hope this helps.

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.YourWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="800"
        Height="600"       
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent"
        ShowInTaskbar="True"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Border CornerRadius="5"
            BorderBrush="#FFAAAAAA"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#DD000000" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#DD333333" Offset="0.50"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#DD393939" Offset="0.49"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#DD666666"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Hello World!" FontSize="16"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to resize and change the color of the Windows OS border. Your solution can be useful in WPF but not in windows forms. Also, i need to be able to move the windows in the screen.

Comment: That's what i have said in other comment. So why you tagged this question with WPF?

Comment: I need a solution for both Winforms and WPF. Adding a border like this, is not possible in winforms.

Comment: Doing that thing is not as simple in WinForms, because the O.S. is in between... Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613418/change-the-style-of-winform-border

Comment: Yes I read that question before. But its not what I need. I want to change the color and the size of the border. As I said, its easy to do in WPF but not in Winforms. I also checked that codeplex app but didnt like it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good solution for both WinForms and WPF. So your question is not really answerable.

The only way for you to get what you're looking for is to draw the borders yourself and handle the resize/move yourself.

However, all of those actions are different between WPF and WinForms. They can be done in both. But it's different in both. So there is no one answer to your question.

Furthermore, you might get a little bit further with people (And not as many downvotes) if you actually showed what you had tried. Did you hit a roadblock doing a particular way? Or are you asking us to brainstorm it all for you?

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried different ways. First, I used a solution that worked in both Winform and WPF. I hide all buttons in the border so then i just have the border. But i realized that if you are using the app in Windows XP for example, the border will be blue. It doesnt looks nice. I know that i can use plenty of things for WPF. I solve it in WPF. But in Winforms I just dont know how to draw a border. Its not easy to try to get the same visual desing using those two technologies. Thats why i was asking if anybody know how to implement it. I dont want someone to paste all the code i need, but to

Comment: give me a piece of advice or idea. thats all.

Comment: That would have been a good (or at least better) explanation in your original post. That's the kind of thing people want to see before they spend their time trying to answer you.

Comment: I know, you are right. I´ll take that in mind in my next post.